# Unity Shader graph не применяет alpha канал к импортированной модели

Tags: unity3d, шейдеры, graph

Я создаю shader graph, в котором края плавно исчезают с помощью альфа канала. С созданным внутри unity объектом проблем нет - всё работает как надо (на изображении он справа). Но импортированная из блендера модель неправильно отображается - на её края на действует альфа. Я отключил импорт материала у модели. На фотографиях видно, как должно работать и как не работает (это мох если что))
Несколько изображений почему-то добавить нельзя, поэтому я объединил все в одну. Прикладываю в том числе часть shader graph с альфой
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То-есть то что текстура на меш не легла вообще не смущает, хрен с ней... НО КРАЯ! ‍♂️

Comment: Извините, а можно поконкретнее? Как можно это исправить?